# What command do I use to see the start and end block of a file in the file system?

Tags: command-line, filesystems, files

Is there any command that will output the beginning and ending block numbers of any file within the filesystem?

Comment: what file system type: ext2,3,4; btrfs; xfs; zfs, etc...?

Comment: @BeowulfNode42: ext4, ntfs, fat32 are the ones I often deal with... so preferably for these three...

Comment: The question should be improved (be more precise): My first answer would have been some program that opens the file, reads the first block, then seeks to the last block and read that, too. So what is "output" of a block? The block's content, the block's logical address (inside the file, inside the file system, inside the partition, or inside the block device), or the block's physical address (gets interesting if the disk is part of some RAID or LVM). The answers seem much better than the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### hdparm

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for but I believe you can do this using the command `hdparm`, specifically with its `--fibmap` switch.

*excerpt*

```
   --fibmap
          When  used,  this  must  be the only option given.  It requires a 
          file path as a parameter, and will print out a list of the block 
          extents (sector ranges) occupied by that file on disk.  Sector 
          numbers are  given as absolute LBA numbers, referenced from sector 
          0 of the physical device rather than from the partition or 
          filesystem.  This information can then be used for a variety of 
          purposes,  such  as examining the degree of fragmenation of larger 
          files, or determining appropriate sectors to deliberately corrupt 
          during fault-injection testing procedures.

          This option uses the new FIEMAP (file extent map) ioctl() when 
          available,  and  falls  back  to  the older  FIBMAP (file block 
          map) ioctl() otherwise.  Note that FIBMAP suffers from a 32-bit 
          block-number interface, and thus not work beyond 8TB or 16TB.  
          FIBMAP is also very slow, and  does  not  deal well  with  
          preallocated uncommitted extents in ext4/xfs filesystems, unless a 
          sync() is done before using this option.
```

#### Example

Say we have a sample file.

```
$ echo "this is a test file" > afile
```

Now when we run `hdparm`.

```
$ sudo hdparm --fibmap afile 

afile:
 filesystem blocksize 4096, begins at LBA 0; assuming 512 byte sectors.
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0  282439184  282439191          8
```

### filefrag

Another nice method for finding out a file's beginning & ending blocks is `filefrag`. You'll need to use appropriate switches though, to get the desired output. One upside of this tool over `hdparm` is that any user can run it, so no `sudo` is required. You'll need to use the `-b512` switch so that outputs are displayed in 512 byte blocks. Also we need to tell `filefrag` to be verbose.

#### Example

```
$ filefrag -b512 -v afile
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of afile is 20 (8 block of 512 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..       7:  282439184.. 282439191:      8:             eof
afile: 1 extent found
```

### debugfs

A third method for getting a file's LBAs is to make use of `debugfs`. This method will require a little math, but I thought it important to show how one can convert from the extents value reported by `debugfs` to LBAs, for those that might be curious.

So let's start with the file's inode.

```
$ ls -i afile
6560281 afile
```

**NOTE:** We could also use the file's name within `debugfs` but for this demonstration I'm going to use the inode instead.

Now let's get the `stat` information via `debugfs` about our inode.

```
$ sudo debugfs -R "stat <6560281>" /dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home
debugfs 1.42.7 (21-Jan-2013)
Inode: 6560281   Type: regular    Mode:  0664   Flags: 0x80000
Generation: 1999478298    Version: 0x00000000:00000001
User:  1000   Group:  1000   Size: 20
File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
Links: 1   Blockcount: 8
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x52be10c3:a640e994 -- Fri Dec 27 18:44:03 2013
 atime: 0x52bff8a1:a9f08020 -- Sun Dec 29 05:25:37 2013
 mtime: 0x52be0fe7:18a2f344 -- Fri Dec 27 18:40:23 2013
crtime: 0x52be0dd8:64394b00 -- Fri Dec 27 18:31:36 2013
Size of extra inode fields: 28
Extended attributes stored in inode body: 
  selinux = "unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0\000" (37)
EXTENTS:
(0):35304898
```

The important information is in the extents section. These are actually filesystem blocks that are being used by this inode. We just need to convert them to LBA. We can do this through the following equation.

**NOTE:** Assuming that our filesystem uses 4k block sizes and that underlying hardware uses 512 byte units, we need to multiply the exents by 8.

```
beginning LBA = (BEGIN EXTENT) * 8
ending LBA    = (((ENDING EXTENT) + 1) * 8) - 1
```

#### Example

So in our example our beginning and ending extent is the same, since our file fits within a single extent.

```
beginning LBA = 35304898 * 8             = 282439184
ending LBA    = ((35304898 + 1) * 8) - 1 = 282439191
```

So our LBAs are 282439184..282439191.

#### References

- [Finding what hard drive sectors occupy a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444844/finding-what-hard-drive-sectors-occupy-a-file)
- [Identifying file associated with unreadable disk sector](http://www.gra2.com/article.php/20041015232512624)
- [Bad block HOWTO for smartmontools](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html)
- [C5170 Lecture notes -- Internal Representation of Files - The Unix File System](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~rich/class/cs170/notes/FileSystem/rich.fs.html)
- [Logical block addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing)
- [Ext4 Disk Layout](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout)

Comment: MANY thanks! Some notes and corrections: `hdparm` does not display the file size, and “holes” can at best be inferred by `byte_offset` not matching 512*accumulated-`sectors`. `filefrag` needs `-e` as well (which changes its output format slightly, but makes it consistent no matter if FIEMAP or FIBMAP is used) and needs sudo if FIBMAP is used (or forced with `-B` to test this; `hdparm` has no way to force FIBMAP).

Comment: To get the extents of a file via `debugfs`, you can use this as well: `sudo debugfs -R "blocks \"$(realpath afile)\"" /dev/sda1`

Answer (score 7):

#### Sector number relative to the block device holding the FS (not whole disk)

(Note that `hdparm --fibmap` is relative to the whole disk, not the partition or whatever other blockdev holds the FS.  It also requires root.)

`filefrag -e` works well, and uses the [generic and efficient `FIEMAP` ioctl](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/fiemap.txt), so it should work on pretty much any filesystem (including the often-weird BTRFS, even for BTRFS-compressed files).  It will fall back to FIBMAP for filesystems / kernels without FIEMAP support.

```
$ filefrag xpsp3.vdi          # some old sparse disk image I had lying around
xpsp3.vdi: 110 extents found
$ filefrag -e xpsp3.vdi
Filesystem type is: 58465342
File size of xpsp3.vdi is 5368730112 (1310726 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..       5: 1322629241..1322629246:      6:            
   1:       13..      13: 1322620799..1322620799:      1: 1322629247:
   2:       15..      47: 1323459271..1323459303:     33: 1322620800:
...
 160:   899498..  915839: 1325792977..1325809318:  16342: 1325725438:
 161:  1307294.. 1307391: 1323938199..1323938296:     98: 1325809319: last
xpsp3.vdi: 110 extents found
```

---

#### XFS-only

If you are using xfs, then `xfs_bmap` has nicer output: It shows you where there are holes, while `filefrag` just has the next extent starting at a later sector.  It uses 512B blocks, not whatever the filesystem blocksize actually is.  (typically 4k on Linux).  It shows you which allocation-group each extent is in, and how it is aligned on RAID stripe boundaries.

```
$ xfs_bmap -vvpl xpsp3.vdi   # the extra -v prints a key to the flags
xpsp3.vdi:
 EXT: FILE-OFFSET           BLOCK-RANGE              AG AG-OFFSET              TOTAL FLAGS
   0: [0..47]:              10581033928..10581033975 13 (83912..83959)            48 01111
   1: [48..103]:            hole                                                  56
   2: [104..111]:           10580966392..10580966399 13 (16376..16383)             8 01010
   3: [112..119]:           hole                                                   8
 ...
 322: [10458352..10459135]: 10591505592..10591506375 13 (10555576..10556359)     784 01111
 323: [10459136..10485807]: hole                                               26672
FLAG Values:   # this part is only here with -vv
    010000 Unwritten preallocated extent
    001000 Doesn't begin on stripe unit
    000100 Doesn't end   on stripe unit
    000010 Doesn't begin on stripe width
    000001 Doesn't end   on stripe width
```

`-l` is redundant when `-v` is used, but for some reason I always type `-vpl`.  `-pl` is more compact output.

---

#### Both `filefrag` and `xfs_bmap` show you preallocated extents.

```
$ fallocate --length $((1024*1024*8)) prealloced_file
$ filefrag -e prealloced_file
Filesystem type is: 58465342
File size of prealloced_file is 8388608 (2048 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..    2047: 1325371648..1325373695:   2048:             last,unwritten,eof
prealloced_file: 1 extent found
$ xfs_bmap -vvpl prealloced_file 
prealloced_file:
 EXT: FILE-OFFSET      BLOCK-RANGE              AG AG-OFFSET            TOTAL FLAGS
   0: [0..16383]:      10602973184..10602989567 13 (22023168..22039551) 16384 10010
 FLAG Values:
    010000 Unwritten preallocated extent
    001000 Doesn't begin on stripe unit
    000100 Doesn't end   on stripe unit
    000010 Doesn't begin on stripe width
    000001 Doesn't end   on stripe width
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=prealloced_file conv=notrunc bs=4k count=10 seek=10000
40960 bytes (41 kB) copied, 0.000335111 s, 122 MB/s
$ xfs_bmap -vpl prealloced_file                                           
prealloced_file:
 EXT: FILE-OFFSET      BLOCK-RANGE              AG AG-OFFSET            TOTAL FLAGS
   0: [0..16383]:      10602973184..10602989567 13 (22023168..22039551) 16384 10010
   1: [16384..79999]:  hole                                             63616
   2: [80000..80895]:  10603013120..10603014015 13 (22063104..22063999)   896 00111
 # oops, wrote past EOF and extended the file, instead of in the middle of the preallocated extent
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=prealloced_file conv=notrunc bs=4k count=10 seek=100
40960 bytes (41 kB) copied, 0.000212986 s, 192 MB/s
$ xfs_bmap -vpl prealloced_file 
prealloced_file:
 EXT: FILE-OFFSET      BLOCK-RANGE              AG AG-OFFSET            TOTAL FLAGS
   0: [0..16383]:      10602973184..10602989567 13 (22023168..22039551) 16384 10010
   1: [16384..79999]:  hole                                             63616
   2: [80000..80895]:  10603013120..10603014015 13 (22063104..22063999)   896 00111
# If you check *right away*, XFS's delayed allocation hasn't happened yet.
# FIEMAP on xfs only reflects allocations, which lag behind completed writes.  fsync first if you need it, IIRC.
$ xfs_bmap -vpl prealloced_file 
prealloced_file:
 EXT: FILE-OFFSET      BLOCK-RANGE              AG AG-OFFSET            TOTAL FLAGS
   0: [0..799]:        10602973184..10602973983 13 (22023168..22023967)   800 10111
   1: [800..879]:      10602973984..10602974063 13 (22023968..22024047)    80 01111
   2: [880..16383]:    10602974064..10602989567 13 (22024048..22039551) 15504 11010
   3: [16384..79999]:  hole                                             63616
   4: [80000..80895]:  10603013120..10603014015 13 (22063104..22063999)   896 00111
$ filefrag -e prealloced_file 
Filesystem type is: 58465342
File size of prealloced_file is 41000960 (10010 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..      99: 1325371648..1325371747:    100:             unwritten
   1:      100..     109: 1325371748..1325371757:     10:            
   2:      110..    2047: 1325371758..1325373695:   1938:             unwritten
   3:    10000..   10111: 1325376640..1325376751:    112: 1325373696: last,eof
prealloced_file: 2 extents found
```

---

`hdparm --fibmap` is only useful if you want a sector number **relative to the entire hard drive**, *not* within the partition the filesystem is on.  It doesn't work on top of software RAID (or presumably anything else between the filesystem and a hard drive).  It also requires root.  Despite the name of the option, it actually uses `FIEMAP` when available (the newer extent-map ioctl, not the old slow block-map ioctl).

```
# hdparm --fibmap ..../xpsp3.vdi
Unable to determine start offset LBA for device, aborting.
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for a given file, you want to know which disk block
numbers contain the start and end of that file.

debugfs(8) looks promising for ext2/3/4 FSes

stat(1), ls -i, lsof(8) provide the inode number,
but not much else about disk blocks.

head/tail --bytes=1024  is useful for file content,
but not disk blocks.

dd(1) will be what you want to inspect the block
contents - be alert to the difference between the
seek= and skip= parameters, and avoid of=/dev/...
unless you *really* want the output file to be a device.

Comment: no that's not what I meant... its the disk's block numbers I'm concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

`hdparm --fibmap` will list the blocks a file occupies.  Note that they may not be contiguous, so "start and end" doesn't make sense.