# How can I find out a file's range of LBA's using its inode?

Tags: filesystems

While answering this U&L question titled: [What command do I use to see the start and end block of a file in the file system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106802/what-command-do-i-use-to-see-the-start-and-end-block-of-a-file-in-the-file-syste), I tried to figure out if it was possible to determine a file's LBA using it's inode.

My answer determined that I could use `hdparm` as one method for finding LBAs:

```
$ sudo hdparm --fibmap afile 

afile:
 filesystem blocksize 4096, begins at LBA 0; assuming 512 byte sectors.
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0  282439184  282439191          8
```

But I was curious if there was some method using a file's inode to also get the LBA's; without using `hdparm`.

I think there might be alternative methods hiding in the tools `filefrag`, `stat`, `debugfs`, and `tune2fs` but teasing it out is eluding me.

Can anyone think of alternatives?

---

*Here's some of my research thus far that might be useful to those brave enough to attempt to answer this.*

#### filefrag

I suspect you could use the tool `filefrag` to do it, specifically using the results from its `-e` switch, perhaps by performing several calculations to get there that I'm not that familiar with.

*sample output*

```
$ filefrag -e afile
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of afile is 20 (1 block of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..       0:   35304898..  35304898:      1:             eof
afile: 1 extent found
```

#### inodes

Another potential method I suspect might have potential is to use a file's inode information, either directly or through some complex math that is poorly documented on the interwebs.

*Example*

First we find out the file's inode. We can do this using either the `stat` command or `ls -i`.

*stat*

```
$ stat afile 
  File: ‘afile’
  Size: 20          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 6560281     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    saml)   Gid: ( 1000/    saml)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2013-12-27 18:40:12.788333778 -0500
Modify: 2013-12-27 18:40:23.103333073 -0500
Change: 2013-12-27 18:44:03.697317989 -0500
 Birth: -
```

*ls -i*

```
$ ls -i 
6560281 afile
```

With the inode information in hand, we can now open up the filesystem this file resides on using the tool, `debugfs`.

**NOTE:** To determine the filesystem a file resides on you can use the command `df <filename>`.

Now if we run `debugfs` and run the command `stat <inode #>` we can get a list of extents that contain this file's data.

```
$ sudo debugfs -R "stat <6560281>" /dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home
debugfs 1.42.7 (21-Jan-2013)
Inode: 6560281   Type: regular    Mode:  0664   Flags: 0x80000
Generation: 1999478298    Version: 0x00000000:00000001
User:  1000   Group:  1000   Size: 20
File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
Links: 1   Blockcount: 8
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x52be10c3:a640e994 -- Fri Dec 27 18:44:03 2013
 atime: 0x52be0fdc:bbf41348 -- Fri Dec 27 18:40:12 2013
 mtime: 0x52be0fe7:18a2f344 -- Fri Dec 27 18:40:23 2013
crtime: 0x52be0dd8:64394b00 -- Fri Dec 27 18:31:36 2013
Size of extra inode fields: 28
Extended attributes stored in inode body: 
  selinux = "unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0\000" (37)
EXTENTS:
(0):35304898
```

Now we have the extents information above, and this is where I get lost and do not know how to proceed.

#### References

- [Finding what hard drive sectors occupy a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444844/finding-what-hard-drive-sectors-occupy-a-file)
- [Identifying file associated with unreadable disk sector](http://www.gra2.com/article.php/20041015232512624)
- [Bad block HOWTO for smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto)
- [C5170 Lecture notes -- Internal Representation of Files - The Unix File System](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Erich/class/cs170/notes/FileSystem/rich.fs.html)
- [Logical block addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing)
- [Ext4 Disk Layout](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to convert from extents to LBAs is actually fairly straightforward once you understand where the numbers are coming from. [@StephaneChazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106869/7453) was critical to gaining this understanding.

#### Original debugfs output

Using the following example that was mentioned in the question.

```
$ sudo debugfs -R "stat <6560281>" /dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home
debugfs 1.42.7 (21-Jan-2013)
Inode: 6560281   Type: regular    Mode:  0664   Flags: 0x80000
Generation: 1999478298    Version: 0x00000000:00000001
User:  1000   Group:  1000   Size: 20
File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
Links: 1   Blockcount: 8
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x52be10c3:a640e994 -- Fri Dec 27 18:44:03 2013
 atime: 0x52be0fdc:bbf41348 -- Fri Dec 27 18:40:12 2013
 mtime: 0x52be0fe7:18a2f344 -- Fri Dec 27 18:40:23 2013
crtime: 0x52be0dd8:64394b00 -- Fri Dec 27 18:31:36 2013
Size of extra inode fields: 28
Extended attributes stored in inode body: 
  selinux = "unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0\000" (37)
EXTENTS:
(0):35304898
```

With the extents information we can do the following calculations. But we need one additional piece of information. The underlying filesystem's block size. You can use this command to get it.

#### Block size

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home | grep "Block size"
Block size:               4096
```

#### Converting from Extents to LBAs

So the key transformation to recognize here is that LBAs are in 512 byte units and the above `debugfs` command that reported the number of extents, is reporting that in 4096 byte blocks.

So, 4096/512 = 8. So we need to multiply the extents by 8 to convert them to LBA values.

So the following math will give us our beginning LBA:

```
$ calc -d
; 35304898 * 8
    282439184
;
```

So what's our ending LBA? To get that we need to recognize that our inode fits inside a single block so its ending extent is the same as its beginning extent. To calculate the ending LBA we can use this equation.

```
ending LBA = ( (extent + 1) * 8 ) - 1
```

So performing this calculation:

```
$ calc -d
; ( (35304898 + 1) * 8 ) - 1
    282439191
```

#### Confirming the results

Looking at the original `hdparm` output:

```
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0  282439184  282439191          8
```

We see that things match.

#### Another example

Just to make sure we're right here's a larger file as a 2nd example.

```
$ ls -i util-linux-2.19.tar.bz2 
6559005 util-linux-2.19.tar.bz2
```

Here's the inode's extents.

```
$ sudo debugfs -R "stat <6559005>" /dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home
...
EXTENTS:
(0-1068):26473396-26474464
```

Now we do of conversions from extents to LBAs.

```
$ calc -d
; 26473396*8
    211787168
; (26474464+1)*8 - 1
    211795719
```

And we confirm.

```
$ sudo hdparm --fibmap util-linux-2.19.tar.bz2 
...
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0  211787168  211795719       8552
```

And we match again.

Comment: An easier way to get the block size may be `stat -fc %S /path/to/file-or-mountpoint`.

Answer (score 5):

`filefrag` and `debugfs` report offset expressed in number of filesystem blocks.

To get the offset in number of 512 byte units, you need to multiply by the size of the block in 512 byte units. On ext4 FS, block size is often 4k, so you need to multiply by 8.

With `filefrag`, you can also use a `-b 512` option to get the offset in 512 byte units.

You can get the block size with the `stats` command in `debugfs`, or with GNU stat:

```
stat -fc%s /mount/point
```

(or any file in that filesystem).

Note that `hdparm` is a hard-disk utility, it will try to give the offset within the disk as opposed to the block device the file system is mounted on (assuming that block device does reside on disk somehow). It only works that way for partitions (by adding the content of `/sys/class/block/the-block-device/start` to the actual offset), and md RAID 1 devices, but not other possibly disk backed block device types like device mapper devices, other RAID levels, dmraid devices, loop, nbd... Also note that older versions of `hdparm` relied on the FIBMAP ioctl which is limited in what block device it can be use on, while newer versions use FIEMAP like `filefrag`.

So, for instance, if you have an `ext2` filesystem on `/dev/sda1`.

```
# hdparm --fibmap /file/in/there
/file/in/there:
 filesystem blocksize 1024, begins at LBA 2048; assuming 512 byte sectors.
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0     109766     109767          2
```

You can get those two sectors (but note that the file likely uses only part of it):

```
dd skip=109766 count=2 if=/dev/sda # not /dev/sda1
```

While with `filefrag` or debugfs.

```
# filefrag -v /file/in/there
Filesystem type is: ef53
Filesystem cylinder groups is approximately 12
File size of /file/in/there is 87 (1 block, blocksize 1024)
 ext logical physical expected length flags
   0       0    53859               1 merged,eof
```

You get it from the actual block device:

```
dd bs=1024 skip=53859 count=1 if=/dev/sda1
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, if `filefrag -b512 -v ..` says "physical_offset: 211787168.. 211795719" these would equate to the LBAs? This seems to jive with the same file with `hdparm --fibmap`, 211787168..211795719. If I drop the `-b512 -v` and use the def. 1024, and attempt to mult. by 8, 26473396⋅8..26474464⋅8, I get 211787168..211795712, which is close but a bit off. I'm thinking the 2nd value should be (26474465⋅8)-1 = 211795719, not sure why though.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get the blocks in 512 units from debugfs?

Comment: I ended up doing the calculations to convert from extents to LBAs using the same math above.